# Ruby include? on each.line.any?

Tags: ruby

I am looking to search for multiple strings from each line of a log file

```
     if
        File.open('filename.log').each_line.any?{|line| ["ERROR:", "***Error",].include?(line) }
        puts 'Pass'
        else
        puts 'Fail'
     end
     gets
```

The program keeps outputting `Fail`, but the log file does contain 'ERROR:' on one line and '***Error' on another line

I'm new to Ruby so any help would be greatly appreciated

After reviewing your helpful answers, I think my initial question is incorrect and misleading. My apologies.

I was looking to verify that a log file contains multiple sentences.

rb file
["All times are valid", "Export complete"]

Log File contents
[Time Stamp] [file_name] All times are valid
[Time Stamp] [file_name] Export complete

Results in Pass

Log File contents
[Time Stamp] [file_name] All times are valid
[Time Stamp] [file_name] Export failed

Results in Fail

Is there something other than .any? I could use?

Thanks

Comment: @lurker Not at all. Ruby can chain enumerators no problem `[3,1,6].each.with_index.any? { |x, i| x == i } # true`.

Comment: @Max yes I'm aware that chaining works. I was thinking that for the `each_line` in that context it wasn't doing what the OP thinks it does in that form. The chaining is allowed because an error isn't thrown. But it obviously didn't provide the desired result. I removed my comment since my wording was probably vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you want to check that each phrase appears at least in the log, you can use a combination of `all?` and `any?`. Basically use `all?` to iterate through the required phrases and `any?` to check each line for the phrase.

```
required = ["All times are valid", "Export complete"]
log = File.open('filename.log')
result = required.all? do |phrase|
    log.any? { |line| line.include?(phrase) }
end
puts result ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'
```

If you are searching for many phrases in a large log, you might find this slow since it will need to make multiple passes of the same line. You could change it around to check each line just once:

```
required = ["All times are valid", "Export complete"]
log.each do |line|
    required.delete_if { |phrase| line.include?(phrase) }
    break if required.empty?
end
puts required.empty? ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'
```

Comment: I have updated my question with more information. I think my question was misleading. Your first example always returns Pass if one of the words is present whereas I require all words to be present for it to pass. Maybe I should use something other than .any?

Comment: I have changed the answer to check that each of the required phrases is present.

Comment: Great, thanks. The Log files are currently small, so will initial use the first example. I ended up storing the result (due to checking multiple log files) and generated an HTML file to display the results. Also, added your site to my feedly; some great stuff on your there!

Comment: Using your first example with - log = File.open('filename.log') - will return with a 'Pass'
However, when I use - log = Dir.glob("\filepath\*.log").select { |f| f.include?('Export')}
Will return a Fail
I've included require'FileUtils' and made sure its finding the same log file. Any reason why it would return different outcomes? Do i need to somehow open the log file once selected?

Comment: `Dir.glob("\filepath*.log").select { |f| f.include?('Export')}` returns an array of file names that include the word "Export" (as Strings). That is very different than how `log` was defined in this answer, which is a `File`. If you want to test multiple files, you will need to open each of the files.

Comment: I'm trying to run multiple ruby scripts and batch files one after another and the reason i'm trying the above is that the log filename, generated in the initial stages, contains a timestamp so its full filename is unknown when start the whole process. The directory will only contain one export log file so i'm trying to figure out how to open that log file without knowing its actual filename so I can then check to see it includes the required phrases.

Comment: Maybe you want to do `log = File.open(Dir.glob("\filepath*.log").first)`?

Answer (score 0):

@Justin has explained why you are having the problem. I wasn't sure if you were searching for words or substrings.  If the former, `"NOERROR:"` would not match; if the latter, it would. Justin assumed the former.  If it's words you're looking for, one way to do that is to use array intersection:

```
error_words = ["ERROR:", "***Error"]
line1 = "Is there an ERROR: here?"
line2 = "Is there a NOERROR: here?"

def check_it(line, error_words)
  puts ((line.split(/\s+/) & error_words).any?) ?  "fail" : "pass" 
end

check_it(line1, error_words) #=> "fail"
check_it(line2, error_words) #=> "pass"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular expression to test for error lines if you want to be a bit more picky:

```
class LogFile
    def initialize(fn)
        @lines = IO.readlines(fn)
    end
    def errors?
        @lines.any? do |line|
            !/^ERROR\:/.match(line).nil?
        end
    end 
end

require 'test/unit'
class TestLogFile < Test::Unit::TestCase

    def testErrors
        log = LogFile.new('filewitherrors.log')
        assert(log.errors?)
    end

    def testErrorsWithCleanFile
        log = LogFile.new('okfile.log')
        assert(!log.errors?)
    end
end
```